# Why are all my variables objects instead of numerical values (int,float) when uploaded?

Tags: pandas, object, variables, scaling, dtype

I just started so that might be stupid, but I have following problem:
I created a .csv-file for some basic data description. However, although they are all numerical values without any missing values when using df.dtyped() I receive all variables as objects with only some being int64 or float64. Do I have to manually convert all object variables to numerical ones with code?
Or is there anything I did wrong when creating my csv?

Also the date I have saved in the format yyyy-mm-dd is shown as object instead of date format.

The numbers of the data range from [0,2] for some variables and [0,2000000] for others.
Could the formatting in Excel be a problem?

Is there any "How to build your csv"-documentation? So that I dont have to ask stupid beginner questions like this?

Additionally, I was told for a model to work properly I need to do some Scaling/Normalization of my data as the value ranges differ a lot.. Where can I find more information on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you just do data type conversion before saving the CSV file. you can use the below function as well for conversion.

`astype()`

`to_numeric()`

`convert_dtypes()`

you can use the attached link for scaling information. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/07/types-of-feature-transformation-and-scaling/

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_csv` has already an option to specify the type so if you want you can specify the `dtypeType with read_csv`. For the date, you always have to change the format to `datetime`

To scale or normalize your date is going to depend on which machine learning model you are going to use also.
For example : if use a random forest and a KNN, the KNN will need to have scaling feature since it works with distance.

**Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and Tensorflow: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques to Build Intelligent Systems** is a good book to start in my personal opinion

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas.
In the end a `pd.readcsv(title, decimal:',')` helped to create them as floats. As I used german formatting.

But conversion with `to_numeric()` also worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).